# Buggy Rails app: test or refactor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, refactoring, project-management

This app had virtually no tests in place when we came to it and now there are cucumber tests covering the most essential parts. We are not sure if the app is working correctly and have had many disasters happen over the course of development, most of them caused by bugs that were never discovered. The code is quite ugly in places with models generating HTML and PHP-itis in the views. There are many extraneous models and controllers that could be greatly simplified or eliminated. My question is, when is it better to simply refactor code without testing previous functionality? Due to deadline constraints, it's very hard to justify spending time on covering all the existing code with tests when we know it's bad and could be easily eliminated.

Comment: If it's hard to justify covering more code with tests, how will it be possible to justify refactoring (which in this case I guess means practically re-writing the code)?

Comment: Refactoring can be done along-side of bug fixes and adding features but writing tests on a large code base would mean practically stopping all development.

Comment: Why would writing tests halt development completely? We have a large code base where there's an on-going effort to increase test coverage which was virtually non-existent originally. Developers successfully spend time on writing tests *as well as* adding new features on a tight release schedule.

Comment: We spent over a month writing the cucumber tests when we first got this project. That has been immensely useful but it only covers the core features. If we wanted to approach 100% test coverage we would have to drop everything we're doing for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna guess this is a client project.  My approach would be to write Cucumber tests to cover the **behavior** of the project only, and then write RSpec implementation tests that cover the new code you'll be writing.

Get the client to sign off on the behavior tests, this way, when you start changing the implementation, you can be sure you haven't drastically modified the behavior of the app. Then, write the tests for the code you wish you had, and refactor until the tests are all green.